# Use Cygwin ftpd standalone

Tags: linux, cygwin, ftp

For sharing files between a guest Linux running in a virtual machine and the host system, the plain old FTP seems sufficient to me.

I intend to use the host, Win7 + Cygwin, as the FTP server. How-to's I have seen configure the FTP server as a Windows service.

Is it possible to run `ftpd.exe` directly, as a standalone executable?

I appended to `/etc/passwd`:

```
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/home:
```

and I run in the Cygwin terminal

```
/usr/sbin/ftpd.exe -dDl
```

Given:

```
netsh interface ip show address "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" | grep IP   

IP address:                           192.168.56.1
```

then, in the guest Linux OS (an ArchLinux ISO) I run:

```
ftp 192.168.56.1
```

but I get:

```
Connected to 192.168.56.1. 
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
```

Note that the problem persists when Windows Firewall is disabled.

Comment: which virtual-machine software do you use?

Comment: VirtualBox with a  Host-Only Network.

Comment: instead of using ftp*: http://askubuntu.com/questions/366742/how-to-share-the-files-from-host-to-guest-in-virtual-box-host-ubunutu-guest-ubu https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Comment: @akira: I can't install shared folders in the ArchLinux ISO. Setup often requires restart and changes go away.

Comment: then just use ssh.

Comment: @akira: I don't get you. I have to read/copy some file from a folder on the host to the guest. SSH is not meant for this. Perhaps you meant SFTP: but why do I need to encrypt the communication and make my life less easy if everything happens inside my notebook?

Comment: a) because by that argument you could just use `nc` b) ssh is started by default on most of the distros, 'ftp' is not. you are having problems with starting ftp ... since ssh is most likely already running, the ssh-route would make your live much easier c) i meant ssh because "sftp" means "ssh file transfer protocol" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol d) you can use a very fast cipher to speed the transfer up quite some bit, http://blog.famzah.net/2010/06/11/openssh-ciphers-performance-benchmark/

Comment: e) to run an ftpd on microsoft windows to share files works around what's build in windows already: samba (or "cifs"). create a window-share on your windows-7 and just access it from within your virtual-linux. allthough i still think that this is the wrong route.

Comment: @akira: a) In fact I am using it now; 
b) Wrong: FTP is already in the Arch ISO;
c) "sftp means ssh file transfer protocol" and in fact I need to transfer files, not remote commands;
d) Encryption is pointless in my use case and would involve installing again a Cygwin server on the host;
e) Again, CIFS protocol is not in the Arch ISO. Simple to fix with `pacman -Sy cifs-utils`, but see [here](http://serverfault.com/q/619212/186731). Now do you realise you are speaking about everything except what I asked? configuring a *stupid* Cycwin FTP server. Oh well, almost, you forgot NFS shares))

Comment: b) read what i wrote. you will have a hard time to find any linux distribution nowadays which has a ftpd (the server-part) running at default. sshd on the other hand is common. i did not talk about ftp-client and ssh/sftp-client. c) which is why "sftp" is implemented ontop of the ssh-connection. you get sftp for free when you are running a sshd, usually. d) you would not install sshd on windows, you would install it on linux. and then share the files via any sftp-client from windows. you are trying to bend windows instead of using whats already there on linux.

Comment: and yes, i realize that i do not explain how to run servers ontop of cygwin because i think that this is the wrong route for your problem. i often experienced folks asking for help on $topic with a certain solution in mind when their real problem was something else and did not need their "solution" at all.

Comment: why do you use a iso-based linux that is lacking samba/cifs-support when you could run for example https://grml.org/files/grml64-full_2014.03/dpkg.selections ?